# Prevent Activity from defaulting to icon from library project

Tags: android, android-activity, android-library

I have two Android projects: project `A` with a Service, and project `B` containing the main Activity which depends on the Service in project `A`. Project `A` also contains an standalone Activity, but it is not currently being used.

Both projects contain drawables called `ic_launcher.png`. `A` uses the default Android icon, and `B` uses a custom icon for our app.

The problem is that the installed app from project `B` is using the version of the icon from `A` (i.e., it's inheriting the icon from `A` rather than using its own icon). How can I get `A` to use its own icon and not the icon from `B`?

I'm using Eclipse, if it matters. I have been using this project structure for a long time and haven't seen this issue pop up until recently. I suspect I could solve the problem by removing the activity and all the icons from `A`, but I'd rather not do that if I don't have to.

EDIT: this is fundamentally a namespace conflict, since I can apparently to refer to drawables from both the main application and the library project in the manifest. I'd prefer a solution where I can explicitly specify the "namespace" (either project `A` or `B`) in the manifest.

Comment: it would be more better if you share your whole manifest

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to change either the name of your own ic_launcher file or the name of the project A's ic_launcher file.

Like ic_launcher_old or something like that.